# Why are my posts not visible in the mobile version of Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I just have created my personal Facebook account. When I publish a new post on the other fan page wall it is invisible in the mobile version of Facebook (e.g Android or iOS). The same post is visible via normal Facebook.

How I can repair it?

This account was created for my daughter, who is 13 years old.

Is it possible that due to the privacy policy of Facebook for minor users 'her' posts are invisible?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are sorting by "Recent" instead of "Popular" in the feed settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the 3 parallel lines on the right hand side, then scroll down to "Most Recent" under the "Feeds" heading, that will display the most recent threads.

The "NewsFeed" which it defaults to will show the most popular posts.

(as per Android app)